# What does it mean to be less than a constant + $o(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics, definition, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $f:(0, \infty)\to\mathbf{R}$ is bounded (by $B$, say) and non-negative. Then $$l := \limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$ exists. The proof I'm reading now claims that $f(x) \le l + o(1)$, which I'm taking to mean "there exists some $o(1)$ function $g$ such that $f(x) \le l + g(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$." Is this the correct interpretation? If so, what could this function $g$ be?

I know that the definition of limit supremum implies the following: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $x_0$ such that $f(x) < l + \epsilon$ for all $x \ge x_0$. Can we construct an explicit $g$ by getting a bunch of $x_n$'s, going to infinity, chosen with the property that $f(x) < l + 1/n$ for all $x \ge x_n$, and then defining $g$ as piecewise constant? e.g. in terms of indicator functions,
$$g(x) = B\chi_{(0, x_0)}(x) + \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{n}\chi_{[x_n, x_{n+1})}(x).$$

Comment: Yes, your construction makes $g(x)=l+\frac1n$ for $x_n\le x<x_{n+1}$ and we know that $f(x)<l+\epsilon$ there. As we cannot ensure $x_0=0$, it is important to also have the first summand with $B$. Note that (without continuity assumption, for example) $f$ might be $\le 1+o(1)$ and yet unbounded (but here we are given a bound), in which case it would be okay to let $g(x)=f(x)$ on $(0,x_0)$

Comment: @Hagen Ah, good point about defining $g = f$ on the initial segment! This makes my argument work for just "eventually bounded" functions. Good to know, for next time!

Answer (score 0):

The notation "$ p(x)=o(q(x))$ as $x\to \infty$", when $q(x)\ne 0$ for all sufficiently large $x$, means that $\lim_{x \to \infty}|p(x)/q(x)|=0$.For any $q$ it means $$\forall k>0\exists r (|p(x)|\leq k|q(x)|).$$  In particular when $q(x)=1$ it means $\lim_{x\to \infty}|p(x)|=0$. So $f(x)\leq l+o(1) \iff f(x)-l|\leq o(1)\iff f(x)-l \leq q(x)$ for some $q$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}|q(x)|=0.$ Which is just another way of saying $\lim_{r\to \infty}\sup \{f(x):x>r\}\leq l$. For other examples we have $\ln x=o(x)$ and $\sqrt {n^2+2 n}-(n+1)=o(1)$as $x\to \infty$. $$\\$$Note: "$o(q(x))$" is read "little o $q(x)$" or "little o of $q(x)$" (or "small o")  to distinguish it from "big O".  If you see $$\\$$"$a(x)=O(b(x))$ as $x\to \infty$" it means $\exists k>0 \exists r  ( \forall x>r (|a(x)|\leq k|b(x)|).$ For example $99 n=O(n)$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: You start off with "No." yet one of your assertions is exactly what I was asking about: "$f(x) \le l + o(1) \implies f(x) \le l + q(x)$ for some $q$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} |q(x)| = 0$" i.e. for some $q$ which is $o(1)$. When I said "...for some $o(1)$ function $g$" in my post, I was using the phrase "little-o-of-one" as an adjective; perhaps that is the cause of the misunderstanding here.

Comment: i must have mis-read "some o(1) function" as "some function" or something. Generally you  see  o(1)  more often in an equality.